# showmodaldialog definition from Chromium source code

Tags: javascript, git, google-chrome, chromium

Google Chrome has removed the support for showmodaldialog function described at the following blog URL.
 http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html

My webpages have few errors and I am thinking that if I can get the implementation of the showmodaldialog and put it on my base master page.

I am trying to download the source code from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src but getting some SSL errors: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Can anybody provide me the source code of the said method and it's dependent methods so that I can use that directly on my webpages to show the popup.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked based on some wrong assumption. I just found that showmodaldialog use native C++ implementation instead of JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I put the following javascript in the page header and it seems to work.  It detects when the browser does not support showModalDialog and attaches a custom method that uses window.open, parses the dialog specs (height, width, scroll, etc.), centers on opener and sets focus back to the window (if focus is lost). If you are passing window args to the modal you will need to write some additional code to fix that. The popup is not modal but at least you don't have to change a lot of code.  Might need some work for your circumstances.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

  // fix for deprecated method in Chrome 37
  if (!window.showModalDialog) {
     window.showModalDialog = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

        var w;
        var h;
        var resizable = "no";
        var scroll = "no";
        var status = "no";

        // get the modal specs
        var mdattrs = arg3.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < mdattrs.length; i++) {
           var mdattr = mdattrs[i].split(":");

           var n = mdattr[0];
           var v = mdattr[1];
           if (n) { n = n.trim().toLowerCase(); }
           if (v) { v = v.trim().toLowerCase(); }

           if (n == "dialogheight") {
              h = v.replace("px", "");
           } else if (n == "dialogwidth") {
              w = v.replace("px", "");
           } else if (n == "resizable") {
              resizable = v;
           } else if (n == "scroll") {
              scroll = v;
           } else if (n == "status") {
              status = v;
           }
        }

        var left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight / 2) - (h / 2);
        var targetWin = window.open(arg1, arg1, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=' + status + ', menubar=no, scrollbars=' + scroll + ', resizable=' + resizable + ', copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        targetWin.focus();
     };
  }
```